# Can create a website written in python using firebase hosting/database

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-hosting

I just started web development, but I have an app that uses firebase database, so I was wondering if I'd be able to create a website written in python that could use firebase hosting and database? If not what language would I have to use?

Comment: Firebase Hosting does not have the ability to run any code.  It just delivers static content.

Comment: Explain this to me like I'm 5, so can I build a web interface, using python, and data from my database hosted on firebase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Firebase hosting](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting):

> Beyond serving static content, you can use Cloud Functions for Firebase or Cloud Run to serve dynamic content and host microservices on your sites.

JavaScript code can access Firebase databases via the web API from an app or via Cloud Functions.

A Python web server could be set up, for example, running on Google App Engine or Azure, that uses the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup), which has a Python API for Firebase databases.

Comment: Okay I am planning on learning one of the two languages, what would be easier/faster to write it in? I'm kind of on a tight schedule

Comment: If you only have time to learn one language, I would recommend JavaScript first and then quickly switch to Typescript, which is a superset of JavaScript that supports data type checking. Most Angular and Firebase developers use Typescript and the VS Code IDE. That being said, Python is an awesome language with vast library support. My favorite Python IDE is Pycharm.